# Merging two features based on the same branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I'm contributing to a repository called [`jprichardson/fs-extra`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra). I have my fork [`reggi/node-fs-extra`](https://github.com/reggi/node-fs-extra). I developed two separate feature branches that have not been accepted to master yet, I'd like to have a branch that I can use merging both features.

- [branch for `ensureFile` feature](https://github.com/reggi/node-fs-extra/tree/feature/ensurefile)
- [branch for `ensureSymlink & ensureLink` feature](https://github.com/reggi/node-fs-extra/tree/feature/ensurelink-ensuresymlink)

I'd like to have a new branch `enhanced` that is a merge of both of these branches. I've tried merging several times. This is the problem.

- The branch `feature/ensurelink-ensuresymlink` renames the existing `index.js` file [`file.js`](https://github.com/reggi/node-fs-extra/blob/feature/ensurelink-ensuresymlink/lib/ensure/file.js), and creates a new `index.js` file.
- The branch `feature/ensurefile` edits the [`index.js`](https://github.com/reggi/node-fs-extra/blob/dev/ensurefile/lib/ensure/index.js) file.

What I need is to merge `feature/ensurefile`'s `index.js` with `feature/ensurelink-ensuresymlink` file.js.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to get them merged

Make sure your in `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

Create a new `enhanced` branch based on `master` and `checkout`

```
git branch enhanced
git checkout enhanced
```

Merge both features

```
git merge feature/ensurefile
git merge feature/ensurelink-ensuresymlink
```

Make sure `mergetool` is confgured.

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
git config --global merge.tool opendiff
```

Use the `mergetool` to merge them, for me this open up the `FileMerge` app, I read the title of the file at the top of the window, and clicked each section using the arrow keys to select the code block I wanted for that file, they were all pointed the same way. When I was done, I saved with `command+s` and then exited the window with `command+w`, this brought up the next file underneeth the window.

```
git mergetool
```

Checked the status. Several backup files were created from the merge process, I deleted them manually in the text editor.

```
git status
```

Test if the code works.

```
npm test
```

Add a new commit.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "merged features"
```

Push to origin.

```
git push origin enhanced
```